# Is there a way to get 110V AC from a PoE ethernet connection?

Tags: power-over-ethernet

This might be a stupid question, but here goes.

We're building a home, and I decided we should have some RJ45 connectors near the roof for PoE cameras.  However, now that the house is almost done, I'm thinking it would be nice if there was a way to get a regular 110V AC outlet, maybe drawing power from the PoE connector, even if it didn't have a lot of capacity.  I don't want to add a regular outlet now, since they'd have to go through drywall at this point.

Is there a connector/inverter that would do this?

Comment: PoE has a limit of about 25 watts of electrical power.  With such a limited amount of power, using an inverter to convert this source to line power of 120VAC makes no sense.  Any low-powered device that you would probably connect would end up using DC rather than AC voltage, so the inefficiencies (i.e. power losses) converting DC to AC then back to DC is wasteful.  And having an outlet that can only provide less than 20 watts instead of the expected 1500W is impractical.

Comment: I'm sorry, hardware shopping recommendations are off-topic here because they tend to go out of date very quickly. You might be able to help help at [hardwarerecs.se] after looking through their help center.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible because there's not going 110V through an PoE connection.

[WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet) tells us the maximum is about 58 volts DC with very limited WATTS.

Given it is very impractical to use this, there are no convertors to convert it back to a wall outlet. It could be possible to construct something like this, but it would not work reliably. You might be able to power a lamp with it, but any sensible equipment is far likely to get damaged.

See also [this manual](http://www.ieee802.org/3/poep_study/public/mar05/diamond_1_0305.pdf) which has a diagram showing that a 110VAC is converted to 57VDC before being transmitted.

Comment: *" there are no convertors to convert it back to a wall outlet"* -- FYI there are converter circuits used in UPSes to convert 12VDC battery power to sinusoidal (aka AC) or pseudo-sinusoidal line voltage (i.e. 120VAC).  Such a converter could be redesigned for a higher input voltage.

Comment: @sawdust yes, in theory it could be, but I meant: there's no out-of-the-market solution to convert PoE back into a wall outlet.